# How do I get this DIV to display below all the content on this page?

Tags: css

I have a relative `<div>` with a couple of absolutely positioned `<div>`s within it. I want to display a footer `<div>` below all of this content, but for some reason, it's showing up behind one of the `<div>`s instead of below it.

Here is the page:  (I've set the background of the footer div to red so you can see what I mean):

http://wreckedexotics.com/3series2/3series_20091106_001.shtml

Answer (score 1):

The DIV with the green border is absolutely positioned and has a fixed height (set to 740px). The red DIV does not know (and cannot know) where (vertically) the green DIV ends (Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the page flow).

**Solution:**

The DIV with the black border: `overflow:auto`
The DIV with the gray background: `float:left`
The DIV with the green border: `float:right`

(and remove the absolute positioning on these elements if present)

Result:

[image]

Comment: Cool, this seemed to have done the trick:  http://wreckedexotics.com/3series2/test.shtml

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your div 'pics' is absolutely positioned so the footer div is positioned relative to all *other* relative divs on the page.

You shouldn't use absolutely positioned divs who's size affects other content on the page, ideally not at all

Answer (score 0):

float you sidebar to left; and take the position:absolute off from the main div and float it left as well. So it looks like below and this should sort it out.

```
#sidebar{
/*your styles*/
float:left;
}

#maindiv{
/*yourstyles*/
/*postition:absoulte;*/
float:left;
}
```